# Apuntar el idice a nombreCiudad y no a idCiudad

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

En mi bd tengo dos tablas: usuario y ciudad,

```
usuario           ciudad
  idUsuario       idCiudad
  nUsuario        nCiudad
  idCiudad
```

Cuando creo mi FK idCiudad en la tabla usuario, obtengo el identificador de cada ciudad. ¿Para que me imprima el nombre de la ciudad en vez del numero id, como debo relacionar las tablas?
Gracias.

Comment: Investiga sobre `JOIN`

Comment: Saludos, te sugiero revisar: http://www.edu4java.com/es/sql/sql5.html

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que revisar las consultas `INNER JOIN` y un ejemplo con tu `DB` seria

```html
SELECT a.idUsuario,a.nUsuario,b.nCiudad FROM usuario a INNER JOIN ciudad b ON a.idCiudad=b.idCiudad;
```

Donde

- a : tabla usuario
- b : table ciudad
- si `a.idUsuario,a.nUsuario,bnCiudad` lo reemplasas por `*` obtendras todos los atributos de ambas tablas